# How to automate translation for ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, translation, globalization

I have to translate whole project to other language. I decided to do it by local resources files. The translation will be provided by outsource company in excel file.

The manual process of translation will be performed in this steps:

1. Create local resource file for page
2. For each text on page

   - if text is not a label or don't contains Id => format text to be inside label and have id (because resource files can only work with asp.net controls)
   - add annotation to label to use resource file
   - create new item in resource file with translation to that label

It will be repeated for each page in project. As you probably noticed for big project this will be very boring process.

My first idea is to create Visual Studio Addin/Extension which will accept the excel file and perform whole translation

My second idea is to create power shell script which will do the work.

And third idea is to do it by VS macros. I don't know whether Macros can support loading files (for loading excel translation).

I wonder about your thoughts how to automate this translation process.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with following those steps:

1. make pattern placeholder to identify which text to translate (be careful on HTML constraints)
2. make a database table that contains translation (language column, placeholder column and translation column) because of data size
   language   placeholder   translation

   French     *name*        nom
3. set a post build task that will launch your own executable with langage argument that will connect database open your aspx folder and iterate on all aspx page to make translation

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will consider that :)

Comment: you are welcome, if my answer is good thank to mark it. If you take another solution thank to tell us which solution ;-)